# Highlighting instances where an instance of data in two adjacent columns in a row is duplicated in a different row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a Small Excel table, which is liable to expand substantially over time, and each row of data is entered chronologically, in real time. Each row includes a serial number (column B) and an error code (column B). I need to identify occasions when the data in column 2 and the data in column 3 are repeated on later date, in a row whch might be WEEKS or months away from a previous occurrence.

Myself and a colleague, who are in no way good at Excel,but we acknowledge our limitations, have spent all day trying various things - including HOURS on Google. No joy so far

Comment: Are both the serial number *and* the error code really in column `B`? And can you clarify what you mean by "data in column 2 and the data in column 3" and how that relates to the serial numbers and error codes

Comment: Yeah, no.  Oopsie.
Serial number/Identifier in column A. Error code in column B. Various other bits of data in other columns – probably not relevant.

Comment: Over time, various individuals, (identified by serial number) will contact my office, with issues – each of these issues will generate an error code. We have many, many error codes! (and, to be fair, many, many individuals!)
What I am trying to achieve is to readily identify when an individual (serial Number) calls in with the same issue (error code) 3 or more times. This might not happen within a weeks, or even a month – the THIRD call, (and any subsequent calls) from individual with a repeated issue are the ones I want to identify.

Comment: I realise that I could just use the filter option on both columns A and B – and this might indeed be the simplest way of doing it, but I am hoping someone who actually understands Excel (cos I don’t!) can offer an elegant (and simple-ish) solution for me

Answer (score 1):

So here are a few options depending on what you are interested in:

Select your used range in columns `B:C` > New formatting rule > Based on formula

**1)** To highlight only rows that will occur at least one more time later on in your data:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1,COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,$B1,$C$1:C1,$C1)<COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1))
```

[image]

**2)** To highlight only the first occurence of rows that will occur more often:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1,COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,$B1,$C$1:C1,$C1)=1)
```

[image]

**3)** To highlight all rows that have duplicates:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1
```

[image]

**4)** To highlight all rows that have occured before:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,$B1,$C$1:C1,$C1)>1
```

[image]

**5)** Highlight the last occurences of rows that have duplicates before them:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,$B1,$C$1:C1,$C1)>1,COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,$B1,$C$1:C1,$C1)>COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)-1)
```

[image]

I would recommend the 3rd or 4th option due to more calculation on the other ones. I highly recommend you to NOT apply these formulas to whole columns as they will slow down your sheet significantly. What is important to know is that once you add a row to your data Excel automatically should adjust the range to where the rule applies to, to include your new row!

**A)** Before adding new row of data:

[image]

**B)** After adding new row of data:

[image]

Comment: OK – thanks very much
I will have a crack at that when I finish work……I will let you know how it goes. Thanks again